# How the awk's body statement execute?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

```
:~$ awk -F"," '{print $0}' sample.csv
c1,c2,c3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

The above awk command print the csv file content. I don't have any doubt in the above command.

```
:~$ awk -F"," '{print "=====This is table====="}{print $0}' sample.csv
=====This is table=====
c1,c2,c3
=====This is table=====
1,2,3
=====This is table=====
4,5,6
=====This is table=====
7,8,9
=====This is table=====
10,11,12
```

But in the above command I expect after the "=====This is table=====" statement the table will print. But the print statement interrupt in every row of the table.

```
=====This is table=====
c1,c2,c3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

But I expect like this. I need explanation of why the print statement printed inside the table content !!.

```
:~$ awk -F"," 'BEGIN{print "This is table"}{print $0}' sample.csv
This is table
c1,c2,c3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

I know if we give the print statement in BEGIN and END statement ,it will print only one time. If i give any print statement in body statement it will print multiple times. Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the awk script runs once for every record

Comment: See [_Structure of AWK Programs_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Structure_of_AWK_programs) as defined by Wikipedia.

Comment: Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and it'll explain this and much more.

Comment: Lots of information right here on stack overflow. Click the [tag:awk] tag, then click the "Learn more" link. Your question is explained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need explanation of why the print statement printed inside the table
> content

From [`gawk` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

> (...)For each record in the input, gawk tests to see if it matches any
> pattern in the AWK program. For each pattern that the record matches,
> the associated action is executed. The patterns are tested in the
> order they occur in the program.(...)Normally, records are separated
> by newline characters.(...)

Answer (score -1):

Structure of an awk program in a nutshell:

```
[BEGIN{[code]}]        # executed before any input is read
[condition][{action}]  # if exists, condition is evaluated for each input record
[...]                  # for true or non-existent conditions action, if exists, is performed
[END{[code]}]          # executed after all input is read and processed 
                       # or if exit was called
```

Comment: I can barely make sense out of this answer. I can't imagine it will be helpful for someone new to awk, or someone whose first language is not english.

Comment: Yeah, I have to agree. The square brackets are tough to understand (and why is it `[condition][{action}]` (square brackets around both parts separately) but `[BEGIN{[code]}]` (square brackets around everything) instead of `[BEGIN][{code}]` or even more consistently `[BEGIN][{action}]`?). And `for true or non-existent conditions action, if exists, is performed` is extremely hard to parse - if I didn't already know what you were trying to say I don't think I could figure it out.

Comment: As in almost everything `[]` denotes an optionality. _Why `[condition][{action}]`_: You can write `condition` or `{action}` or `condition{action}` or none. _Why `[BEGIN{[code]}]`_: You can write `BEGIN{code}` or (useless) `BEGIN{}` or not use `BEGIN`at all. Maybe adding a comma to _for true or non-existent conditions, action, if exists, is performed_. What comes to my English, it's only my third language, so sorry about that.